# How to obtain a Region from a numerical (!) function

Tags: regions, mesh

I'd like to achieve a `Region` from a purely numerically defined function.
Like this one:

```
f[r_?NumericQ, th_] := {r Cos[th], r Sin[th]};
```

Analytically this is quite easily achievable with:

```
Region[ParametricRegion[{r Cos[th], r Sin[th]}, {{th, 0, 2 Pi}, {r, 0, 1}}]]
```

But how would I do this with the numerically defined `f`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to give [`ParametricRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricRegion) a list as a first argument. Also, [`BoundaryDiscretizeRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoundaryDiscretizeRegion) is a better choice for visualization of a numerical function:

```
Clear[f]
f[r_?NumericQ, th_] := {r Cos[th], r Sin[th]}

BoundaryDiscretizeRegion @ ParametricRegion[
    {Indexed[f[r, th], 1], Indexed[f[r, th], 2]},
    {{th, 0, 2 Pi}, {r, 0, 1}}
]
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any requirements for `f` in `ParametricRegion`? Because if I try it your answer with `f[[0]]` being a `BSplineFunction`, `ParametricRegion` just outputs the input (although it calculates for some time).
I can provide an example if you wish

Comment: I created a different question explaining for which function the `Indexed` solution fails: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/235240/regions-for-numerically-defined-toroidal-surfaces